# How to manage .net dependencies

Tags: ironruby

I am using require to load an assembly from a specific path. 
The assembly I load depends on another assembly that is in the same folder.

When I try to run the code I get an error saying one of the dependencies could not be found. I have discovered that if I put the second dependency in the bin dir then it works - this is not a suitably solution for me. I found this option in ir.exe.config:

```
<set language='Ruby' option='LibraryPaths' value='..\lib\IronRuby;..\lib\ruby\site_ruby\1.8;..\lib\ruby\site_ruby;..\lib\ruby\1.8'/>
```

If I add the path to where my assemblies are then I can use load_assembly and everything works fine.

Is there a way to add a Libary Path at runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes:

```
$LOAD_PATH << 'c:\my\folder\'
```